# Transliteration of Danish characters

Tags: 7, path-aliases

I have a site running with these modules (among others):

- [Pathauto](http://drupal.org/project/pathauto)
- [Transliteration](http://drupal.org/project/transliteration)

My problem comes with danish characters. Normally they would be replaced like this:

- Æ = Ae
- æ = ae
- Ø = Oe
- ø = oe
- Å = Aa
- å = aa

However, the Transliteration module isn't working like I would expect; it replaces:

- Æ = ae
- æ = ae (correct)
- Ø = o
- ø = o
- Å = a
- å = a

So "ÆØÅ - æøå" becomes "aeoa-aeoa".

The "lower case issue" might be caused by the Pathauto module, and it is not neccesarily a problem with the transliteration. Still it's not correctly replaced.

This is a file from the Transliteration module that I think it does the replacement of Danish characters, but I can't figure out how to make it work correctly.

**x00.php**

```
<?php

$base = array(
  // Note: to save memory plain ASCII mappings have been left out.
  0x80 => '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '',
  0x90 => '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '',
  0xA0 => ' ', '!', 'C/', 'PS', '$?', 'Y=', '|', 'SS', '"', '(c)', 'a', '<<', '!', '', '(r)', '-',
  0xB0 => 'deg', '+-', '2', '3', '\'', 'u', 'P', '*', ',', '1', 'o', '>>', '1/4', '1/2', '3/4', '?',
  0xC0 => 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'AE', 'C', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'I', 'I', 'I', 'I',
  0xD0 => 'D', 'N', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'x', 'O', 'U', 'U', 'U', 'U', 'U', 'Th', 'ss',
  0xE0 => 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'ae', 'c', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i',
  0xF0 => 'd', 'n', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', '/', 'o', 'u', 'u', 'u', 'u', 'y', 'th', 'y',
);

// Overrides for Danish input.
$variant['da'] = array(
  0xC5 => 'Aa',
  0xD8 => 'Oe',
  0xE5 => 'aa',
  0xF8 => 'oe',
);

// Overrides for German input.
$variant['de'] = array(
  0xC4 => 'Ae',
  0xD6 => 'Oe',
  0xDC => 'Ue',
  0xE4 => 'ae',
  0xF6 => 'oe',
  0xFC => 'ue',
  0xDF => 'ss',
);
```

**SOLUTION**

When developing I had the language set to English; it needs to be set to Danish, in order to get this to work.

Comment: The same problem with Serbian characters, I need Š > S, Ć > C, Č > C

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOLUTION

When developing I had the language set to English; it needs to be set to Danish, in order to get this to work.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "developing." Suppose I have a site with 4 languages. Obviously I cannot develop it in all four languages. so how does one do it?